# Closing Java FileHandler when quitting a routine that runs as a service

Tags: java, logging, windows-services, filehandler

I have a little routine that schedules a timer like that:

```
timer.schedule(new myRoutine(), 1000, 60000);
```

In the `run()` method of `myRoutine` a `logger` is opened and a `FileHandler` is attached to it:

```
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("app.log"),true);
logger.addHandler(fh);
```

Since there is no real exit point to the application (as it runs as a service), i have no chance to close and remove the `logger`´s `FileHandler`, hence the file lock (`app.log.lck`) remains, resulting in a new logfile (`app.log.1`) on next start of the service.

Is there a way to ensure the `FileHandler` is closed and removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add shutdown hook like this:

In a method that schedules timer:

```
public void scheduleFileTask() {
    final FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("app.log"),true);
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fh.close();
        }
    });
    timer.schedule(new MyRoutine(fh), 1000, 60000);
}
```

And in **MyRoutine.java**

```
public class MyRoutine extends TimerTask {
    private final FileHandler handler;

    public MyRoutine(FileHandler hander) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void run() {
        // use handler here 
        handler.doSomething();
    }
}
```

For more information you can [look up java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

Comment: When I do it that way, the TimerTask can´t "see" the run() method any more and therefore gives a compiler error: "must implement run()"

Comment: You should pass resource to your task. I just edited answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but i don´t get what you mean. The run() method needs to reside in the class that is scheduled by the timer which itself  needs to inherit from TimerTask. But in this case, the run() method cannot be wrapped by the Runtime.getRuntime().

Comment: Ok, forget it. I obviously confused the Hook´s run() method with the Timer´s run() method. The Shutdown hook is nevertheless the technique of choice here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am blind, but why don't you do something like:

```
class MyRoutine {
  public void run() {
    FileHandler fh = null;
    try {
      fh = ...
      whatever else to do ...
    } finally { 
      cleanup fh }
```

Or, maybe, just go for try-with-resource?

You know, even when myRoutine (wrong casiness there, by the way) is a "service"; don't you expect it to be called, do something and then go away?

Comment: No, actually I expect the timer to re-schedule until the service is stopped